# Does macOS 10.13 on macbook pro 2017 support VP8/VP9/AV1 hardware acceleration?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hardware, video

I know that macOS supports h.264 and h.265 hardware decode/encode (videotoolbox). Does it also support VP8/VP9/AV1 hardware decoding? Currently, playing a 4K video on YouTube is a bit slow.

I'm using macOS High Sierra on 13-inch 2017 MacBook Pro with 3.1 GHz Intel Core i5 and Intel Iris Plus Graphics 650 1536 MB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For AV1, no. The only dedicated hardware decoding for AV1 is in NVIDIA's latest GPUs, the 3000 series, Intel's 11th gen chips, and AMD's RDNA2 GPUs.

According to [this discussion](https://old.reddit.com/r/Stadia/comments/kaeajw/vp9_hardware_decoding_on_mac/gf9rdxr/), VP9 hardware decoding is available. On Chrome, check chrome://flags/ to see if "VideoToolbox VP9 Decoding" is enabled.

Comment: What about for FFplay, IINA, and VLC? Do they have support for videotoolbox vp9? What configuration options can I use to enable hardware acceleration?

Comment: Seems like this will not work on my macbook. According to a later thread in that discussion, only 2018+ macbooks support VP9 hardware decoding.